# What is the relationship between static typing and lazy functional languages?

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, scheme, lazy-evaluation

I'm curious about the relationship between static typing and lazy functional languages. Is it possible to have a dynamic lazy functional language, for instance? It seems as if all of the lazy functional languages out there are statically typed (Haskell, Miranda, etc), and all of the dynamic functional languages use strict evaluation (Clojure, Scheme, etc).

In particular, the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) on Lazy evaluation reads:

> However, with lazy evaluation, it is difficult to combine with
>   imperative features such as exception handling and input/output,
>   because the order of operations becomes indeterminate. Lazy evaluation
>   can introduce space leaks.

What is the role that static typing plays in preventing space leaks?

Comment: No relation between these 2 things. Lazy is about `when to evaluate` whereas static typing is about giving the compiler some `extra information` about your code

Comment: @Ankur the fact that these are discrete concepts doesn't mean there isn't a relationship between them in this context.  The questioner is asking whether something about the nature of "lazy" functional languages makes static typing particularly advantageous (or vice versa, perhaps).  This is a very reasonable question to ask, given the observable correspondence between the two features.

Comment: What about the ML family of languages, Josh?  They're statically typed and eager by default, with laziness only available as an option via closures.  Doesn't invalidate your point, though ;)

Comment: SASL the first of David Turner's languages in the Miranda family appears to be untyped (as opposed to statically typed), surprisingly perhaps as it was the _St Andrews Static Language_. I believe Nyquist - Roger Dannenberg's sound synthesis language - is lazy, it doesn't seem very typed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't believe that static types play a role at all. For example, consider the untyped lazy language, [Lazy Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/lazy/index.html). I haven't heard any indication that it leaks space in a way that Haskell (for example) does not.

Side effects, on the other hand, *are* a problem because humans find the order of evaluation of strict evaluation to be (relatively) natural, and call-by-need is much harder to mentally predict.

Comment: That's interesting, so languages like Haskell prevent unintentional side effects through static typing?

Comment: Haskell prevents unintentional side effects by not having any side-effecting primitives (except for things whose name begin with `unsafe`, but they don't count). Type systems that allow for effects but restrict them exist, but Haskell's approach is simpler.

Comment: (Of course, in Haskell it's actually possible to print things out and launch missiles, etc. thanks to the IO monad. You can look at that as a matter of controlling effects with types; I look at it as a matter of *simulating* effects in a system that lacks them.)

Comment: I have to confess I'm a little disappointed to see this accepted as the main answer.  It only answers one of the good questions asked and not, in my view, the most interesting.  No offence meant to Paul; I was just hoping to see a wider variety of ansers.

Comment: @itsbruce I read the title and both sentences ending in question marks as asking approximately the same thing; can you help restate the question you're more interested in?

Comment: You answered the Space Leaks question, which is fine.  But he began by exploring a more general relationship between static typing and lazy evaluation.  "Is it possible to have a dynamic lazy functional language, for instance?"  I may be wrong, but I see him asking if there's some good reason why many functional languages have both characteristics.

Comment: Well, if I had to speculate, I'd guess that a lot of it is just cultural inertia. Any technical reasons are probably pretty minor. For example, there are some things (like making `if` user-defined) that both macros (a favorite of the untyped community) and laziness can do, and even though they are very different technologies, it discourages people from adding both to their language.

Comment: I was thinking **convergence** myself, which I guess is another word for inertia.

Comment: So it's not necessarily a matter of necessity (avoiding unsafe side effects) that prevents the prevalence of dynamic lazy functional languages?

Comment: @JoshVoigts Correct; it's just a matter of culture and style (and perhaps avoiding redundancy, but that's not as strong a factor as it may seem at first).

Answer (score 6):

> What is the role that static typing plays in preventing space leaks?

Types can be used to track the lifetime of objects, statically ensuring the absence of leaks.

An example would be region types and other effect types.

Comment: Could you cite any references that explain this in any detail?  Otherwise, this really just a declaration (however true) that doesn't give the questioner a lot of help.

Comment: Also, I don't quite see how you mean this. What has the lifetime of objects to do with static typing? You can even implement dynamic typing in C++ and still have full RAII (with something like `std::unique_ptr<Object>`).

Comment: @itsbruce : You can look at http://disciple.ouroborus.net/ to see a type system that uses regions in this way.

Answer (score 3):

Lazy evaluation and static typing are independent concepts.

1. **Untyped**

   - **Lazy evaluation** The untyped lambda calculus with [normal order reduction strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_order_reduction#Normal_order) (or *call by need*). Always the leftmost redex is evaluated first.
   - Eager (strict) evaluation The untype lambda calculus with [applicative order reduction strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_order_reduction#Applicative_order).  Lambda terms are always reduced before they're substituted to other terms.
2. **Typed**

   - **Lazy evaluation** Haskell is an example.
   - **Eager evaluation** OCaml is an example.

---

Roughly speaking, evaluation is something that happens when the program is run.
Typing is something that happens when the program is compiled.

But of course there is an important correspondence between a typing system and an evaluation strategy:

> If a term *M* reduces to *N* and *M:σ* (*M* is of type *σ*) then *N:σ*.

This means that when we run a program that has some type *σ* then the value
will have the same type. Without this property, a typing system is really
useless (at least for programming). This also means that once we have typed a
program during compilation, we don't need to remember the typing information
when evaluating it, because we know that the result will have the correct type.

---

Concerning the Wikipedia article you're quoting. There are two different things:

1. Imperative features. This isn't really related to a typing system. The problem is that if evaluating certain expressions has side effects (like I/O in most languages) in lazy settings it's very hard to predict when (if at all) a side effect occurs. Therefore once you have lazy evaluation, it's hardly possible to have an impure language.

   One exception to this is the **[Clean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_%28programming_language%29) language**. It uses a special type system to handle side effects in a lazy setting. So here there is some connection between the evaluation strategy and the typing system through handling side effects: The type system allows handling side effects in such a way that we can keep lazy evaluation.
2. Space leaks. This is a known drawback of lazy evaluation. See [Building up unevaluated expressions](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Memory_leak#Building_up_unevaluated_expressions) or [Ch. 25 Profiling and optimization](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/profiling-and-optimization.html) in Real World Haskell. But again this has nothing to do with type systems - you'd get the same behavior in an untyped language.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you look at things from a more general level, it is possible to observe a natural relationship between static typing and lazy functional languages. The main point of static types is to inform and advance the capabilities of the compiler; surveying the static-dynamic divide among languages, it generally tracks the schism between compiled and interpreted code.

And what is the point of lazy evaluation?

An infamous, retrospective article by Peyton-Jones et al describes lazy evaluation as "the hair shirt" which kept the language purely functional. His metaphor aptly conveys the Haskell community's deep-rooted idealism of denotational semantics. Non-strict evaluation's fundamental benefit is that it transforms the possibilities for structuring code in ways that facilitate this denotational paradigm. In the notorious lazy evaluation debate carried on by Bob Harper and the Haskell community, Prof. Harper demonstrates the challenges lazy evaluation poses for practical programs - and among Lennart Augustsson's defenses of laziness, this one best illustrates the point:

> "I've saved my biggest gripe of strict evaluation for last. Strict evaluation is fundamentally flawed for function reuse. [...] With strict evaluation you can no longer with a straight face tell people: don't use recursion, reuse the recursion patterns in map, filter, foldr, etc. It simply doesn't work (in general). [...] strict evaluation really, fundamentally stops you from reusing functions the way you can with laziness."

And for his example of function reuse via lazy evaluation, Augustsson offers, "*It's quite natural to express the `any` function by reusing the `map` and `or` functions.*" So lazy evaluation emerges from this picture as a rather costly language feature embraced in service of a more natural style of coding.

What else do we need to sustain an abstract, denotational style of coding? A powerful optimizing compiler might come in handy! Thus, even if there is no technical or necessary connection between static types and lazy evaluation, the two features are oriented toward the same goal. It's not so surprising they often appear together.